# inner join a and b in c

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display all row's in table **a,b** where b.id = **C.BId** but i cant put C in my code :(

```
select * 
from ItemData a 
inner join Client b 
    on a.Id = Items.ItemsID 
where b.Id =1
```

error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "Items.ItemsID" could not be bound.

the working code is:

```
select * 
from ItemData a 
inner join Items b 
    on a.Id = b.ItemsID 
where b.ClientID =1
```

return :

```
Id  IGender IDetailing  ITipe   IPrice  IAmount SaveItem    Id  ClientID    ItemsID
1   man     blak        ginz    14.2    0        1          1   1           1
2   wiman   oreng       shirts  34.9    0        0          2   1           2
```

I don't want the Items to be add as you see **Id-ClientID-ItemsID** but i want to add all the Client info table the same row of the first select not the joiner Table(Items)

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your' trying to do this.

```
select *, c.Id, c.ClientId, c.ItemsID 
from ItemData a 
inner join Items b on a.Id = b.ItemsID 
left join Client c on c.ItemsID = b.Id
where b.ClientID =1
```

Since you are using client info, you have to use `inner join`

```
select *, c.Id, c.ClientId, c.ItemsID 
from Client c
inner join Items b on c.ItemsID = b.Id
inner join ItemData a on a.Id = b.ItemsID  
where b.ClientID =1
```

Comment: what lift join is ?

Comment: in case you don't have row that matches your Items from Client Table, it will still display your 2 row.s

Comment: select c.CFerstName,c.CFamileName,c.CNumber,c.CCity,c.CPotCode,c.CHuisnum,a.ITipe,a.IGender,a.IDetailing,a.IPrice,a.IAmount
from ItemData a 
inner join Items b on a.Id = b.ItemsID 
left join Client c on b.ItemsID = c.Id
where b.ClientID =1

Thanks sooo much !!!!!!

Comment: i tried it ! its works but i find out that it will work also without inner or left 
what is the difrent between and are they importent?

Comment: yes, it will work with inner and left join. inner join, in your case, since your using client info, it should be inner join.

Comment: You should not use arbitrary letters for table aliases.  Use abbreviations of table names, so the aliases are meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

**EXAMPLE:**

select * from Student_Details  --Consider As a table

---

select * from Book_Transaction --Consider As b table

---

select * from Books            --Consider As c table

---

Query sample :

```
select a.Name,b.BookId,c.Title  from  Student_Details a **inner join**
 Book_Transaction B on a.StudentId=b.StudentId **inner join**  Books C on B.BookId=**c.BookId**
```

Comment: i tried it ! its works but i find out that it will work also without inner or left 
what is the difrent between and are they importent?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

Inner Join a,b,c

Then Try to apply condtion  **C.Bid**
without joining you cant Use the Table or either its alias name.

Comment: can you give me example